# Multiple Unicorns/Rails Apps, Nginx, One User

Tags: nginx, unicorn

1. I successfully deployed a Rails app using Capistrano, Unicorn, Nginx using the following unicorn configuration:

   ```
   env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"

   worker_processes 4

   listen "/tmp/app_one.socket", :backlog => 64

   preload_app true

   timeout 60

   pid "/tmp/unicorn.app_one.pid"

   if env == "production"
     working_directory "/home/single_user/app_one/current"

     user 'single_user'

     shared_path = "/home/single_user/app_one/shared"

     stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
     stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
   end

   before_fork do |server, worker|
     if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
       ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
     end

     old_pid = "/tmp/unicorn.app_one.pid.oldbin"
     if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
       begin
         Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
       rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
         # already dead
       end
     end
   end

   after_fork do |server, worker|
     if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
       ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
     end
   end
   ```
2. Under the same `single_user`, I added a second Rails app, a second Nginx virtual server, and used the exact same Unicorn config, **replacing `app_one` with `app_two`** in all the appropriate places.
3. My second app deployed just fine, but now I am having trouble deploying app one. The `/tmp/unicorn.app_one.pid` does not exist, but the site still works fine (`top` showing ten processes as expected). However `/tmp/app_one.socket` does exist, which prevents me from starting Unicorn by hand.

**So is this the appropriate practice, to run multiple Rails/Unicorn/Nginx under the same user? Have I caused some kind of conflict in my deployment process? How should I proceed without breaking `app_one`, which is live and in use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use an app-specific tmp directory, and put the unicorn.pid into there, like "#{working_directory}/tmp/unicorn.pid".  Similarly for any app-specific files like the socket. If you don't want to put it in working_directory, use shared_path.  Keep everything specific to app1 in an app1-specific location, and everything related to app2 in an app2-specific directory.

Comment: How do I kill my existing app_one.socket? If I try to deploy, it says address already in use. I made the changes to nginx, and restarted.

Comment: Presumably, the socket is there because unicorn is still running.  You'll need to restart unicorn.  This shouldn't have anything to do with nginx.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I had been trying to kill processes manually, which wasn't working. What worked was `pkill unicorn_rails`. So back to your answer, the socket is defined in Nginx `upstream {}`. You are suggesting that I nest that location in an app-specific directory?

Comment: The nginx directive doesn't create the unicorn socket: it tells nginx how to connect to the backend server. The socket will be created by the unicorn process. But, yeah, put the socket into the app-specific directory.  It'll be neater than fiddling with different file names, since the apps will be separated by base directory.